# service to see if script on each web page?

Tags: php, python, html, saas

Is there a service out there that can alert me if a website (and all sub pages) don't have a script on them/e.g. a web dev does some work on a page and uploads new page live but does not include custom / general scripts on it like custom analytics or custom coding for a page etc.

I know theres a services to tell you if a web site is up and running but i need something more specific :)

Comment: its a simple question. say i have a business website and i have a custom script on say the purchase page that needs to do something when a purchase is made BUT then my designer makes some changes and excludes the custom script from the purchase page. oblivious to this the new page goes live and i lose out on that custom code doing its job. I would want a service to alert me that joeblowcustomcodeX is not live on web page and doing its job ...

Comment: this is going to be closed in 1.023 seconds

Comment: THis question does not make any sense

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN i dont know if this question was supposed to make any sense

Comment: read my description below if you are confused

Comment: Get a better designer? Don't allow access to the file with the script? Create a crawler that checks for the existence of a tag? There are a bunch of ways, but you're going about it wrong.

Comment: yeah easier said than done. they are a dime a dozen and the good ones are really rare. I think i will have to get a script done up using something like what was suggested below (http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) and maybe i can sell it as a saas to other people like me, who i know have the same problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create one yourself using something like [Selenium WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) to scrape your pages and look for the existence of your scripts.

Comment: yeah that looks super promising! :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that can even attempt to mimic maybe this a version control software like `github` or `svn`

Comment: yup for sure, but what if i have a host of ecommerce sites with custom scripts across them all? I cant manually check them all daily / hourly to make sure highly specific code is on the page waiting to do its job. I would want an alert saying "OI - joeblowcustomcodeX on ecommerce site Y doesn't exist and because of this will cost you your mistresses xmas present"

Comment: I would highly recommend fixing your process, rather than trying to bandaid it with tools.

Comment: sure its easier said than done, i go through designers every couple months and i go through the same story of what to include and what not to when uploading enhanced live pages. Its a losing battle trust me, otherwise i would not be here :)

Answer (score 0):

Write your own service to do this? Shouldn't be too hard. Just a fetch + string match.

Comment: alas, i was hoping there was a custom service out there offering it at the moment as i need to get something like it up and running and i just dont have the time for developing it.

Comment: it wouldnt take long at all to put this together... maybe 15-20 mins on the outside

Comment: yeah going to check this out below and put something together - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/